# Как исправить ошибку Past duration 0.хххххх too large в ffmpeg

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ffmpeg

Здравствуйте!

Помогите убрать ошибку при выполнении команды склеивания файлов. Очень желательно без потери качества видео и звука.

```
ffmpeg -i mix.mp4 -i mix.mp3 out.mp4
```

При ее выполнении выскакивают ошибки

```
Past duration 0.хххххх too large
```

и происходит рассинхронизация видео и звука. Пробовал ffmpeg -vsync 1 - аналогично.

Где-то прочитал что может помочь

```
ffmpeg -framerate ...
```

,но ffmpeg ее вообще не знает. Пишет

```
Option framerate not found.
```

Версия ffmpeg

```
dpkg -s ffmpeg | grep VersionVersion: 7:2.8.14-0ubuntu0.16.04.1
```

Answer (score 1):

можно попробовать склеить так:

```
ffmpeg -i mix.mp4 -i mix.mp3 -map 0:0 -map 1:0 -c:v copy -c:a copy out.mp4
```

Comment: Спасибо. То что нужно.

Answer (score 0):

А попробуйте вот так, ради интересу:

```
$ ffmpeg -r 25
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. При -r 18 указанная ошибка не возникает.  Но видео поток падает с 347 до 238 Кбит/сек. Возникает потеря качества.